# Query a table using C# and npgsql where date type field does not contain a date?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

Probably a very simple answer that is making me a bit crazy.

I'm using C# and npgsql to connect to a PostgreSQL database.

I'm trying to either SELECT or INSERT, where the log_date field (Type is date) doesn't have any date in it. Its not set to allow nulls.

I have tried:

```
var pgCommand = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE log_date = '';", connection);

var pgCommand = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE log_date = \"\";", connection);

var pgCommand = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE log_date = NULL;", connection);

var pgCommand = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE log_date = null;", connection);

var pgCommand = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE log_date = '\"\"';", connection);
```

If I do a SELECT and write the data to the console, nothing shows up under the date, which is correct as there is nothing in the log_date field.

How the heck do I check for an empty date?

Thanks,

Neill

Answer (score 2):

It if allows `null`, you can use `is null`, e.g. `log_date is null`. If it doesn't, you're supposed to give it some value - that will usually work out to some default either at the database level or the application level (.NET's default being `01/01/0001 00:00:00`). However, this just hints at a deeper design issue - how come "there's no value" in a column that's not allowed to not have a value?

Comment: Thanks Luaan. log_date is null is what I needed. And my apologies, nulls are allowed. Brain gets a bit frazzled when staring for hours at something so simple and not being able to figure it out. I won't edit my original post because then your comment won't make sense. Thanks again.